# tab content is not loading from ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to load content from ui-router to tab but that is not happening i have a data rendered for each tab through their specify controllers in states. I am not able to see any data in tab, Any idea what is implemented wrong in below code ?

main.html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <uib-tabset active="active">
        <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.heading}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
            <div>{{tab.route}}></div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

app.js

```
 $stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'web/global/main.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.dit', {
                    url: '/dit',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/dit.html',
                    controller: 'DitCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.st', {
                    url: '/st',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/st.html',
                    controller: 'StCtrl'
                })
                .state('app.uat', {
                    url: '/uat',
                    templateUrl: 'view/partials/uat.html',
                    controller: 'UatCtrl'
                })
```

MainCtrl.js

```
 $scope.tabs = [
        { heading:'DIT', route:'app.dit',active:true},
        { heading:'ST', route:'app.st',active:false},
        { heading:'UAT', route:'app.uat',active:false},
    ];

    $scope.go = function(route){
        $state.go(route);
    };

    $scope.active = function(route){
        return $state.is(route);
    };

    $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
        $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Create a codepen or some js playground reproducing the issue.  You'll have a much better chance at receiving an answer.